# How to keep observations for individuals who showed up for the first time in week t in the data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data-frame:

```
   ID       date  X
0   A 2021-12-15  7
1   A 2022-01-30  6
2   A 2022-02-15  2
3   B 2022-01-30  2
4   B 2022-02-15  2
5   B 2022-02-18  7
6   C 2021-12-01  7
7   C 2021-12-15  4
8   C 2022-01-30  2
9   C 2022-02-15  7
10  D 2021-12-16  5
11  D 2022-01-30  4
12  D 2022-03-15  9
```

I want to keep the observations for those IDs who first showed up in week, say, 51 of the year (I would like to change this parameter in the future).

For example, IDs `A` and `D` showed up first in week 51 in the data, `B` didn't, `C` showed up in week 51, but not for the first time.
So I want to keep in this example only the data pertaining to `A` and `D`.

Comment: This isn't a specific programming question, you're asking us to write the code for you. Attempt to do this yourself and then come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter if `week` match variable `week` and it is first time by `ID` in DataFrame by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), then get `ID` values:

```
week = 50

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

s = df.loc[df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week.eq(week) & ~df['ID'].duplicated(), 'ID']
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['ID'])
s = df1.loc[df1['date'].dt.isocalendar().week.eq(week) ,'ID']

print (s)
0     A
10    D
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Last filter by `ID` with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['ID'].isin(s)]
print (df)
   ID       date  X
0   A 2021-12-15  7
1   A 2022-01-30  6
2   A 2022-02-15  2
10  D 2021-12-16  5
11  D 2022-01-30  4
12  D 2022-03-15  9
```

Comment: Thanks. I meant that I want to keep the data of A and D, that is, all their observations. Not only their names.

Comment: @qwerty - answer was edited.